# For auto loop to fill a matrix

Tags: c++, vector

I want to transform a adjacency list to adjacency matrix

The adjacency list is as follows:

```
vector< vector< Arc * > * > _adjacences;
```

and class arc has these:

```
public:
    int sommetArrive; // tops
    int longueur; // distance
```

I have 3 vectors as follows to be filled:

```
std::vector <int> list[_adjacences.size()]; // vector of tops
std::vector <int> >listD[_adjacences.size()]; // vector of distances
std::vector < vector <int> > matrix( _adjacences.size(), 
         vector<int>(_adjacences.size(),0 )); // matrix init to 0 and to be filled to become adjacenecy matrix
```

I filled the vectors this way:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++){
    for (auto j : *_adjacences[i]){
         list[i].push_back(j->sommetArrive);
         listD[i].push_back(j->longueur);
    }
}
```

Now my issue is here: I try to make the adjacency matrix, I was able to make it

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0
....
```

by doing this :

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++) {
    for (auto j : list[i]){
          matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

I want to make the adjacency matrix with distances between the tops instead of 1.

I tried making it this way:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++) {
    for (auto j : list[i]){
         for (auto k : listD[i]){ // MY ERROR IS SOMEWHERE HERE 
              matrix[i][j] = k;   // IN THIS LOOP
         }
     }
}
```

I end up with the same distance in the same row

```
0  0  0  0  35  0  35
0 22  0  22  0  22 0
```

How can i fix my loop ?

Comment: this what I get if I declare it normally: ```error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘list.std::vector<int>::operator[](((std::vector<int>::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>::value_type’ {aka ‘int’}```

Comment: What do you want `list` to be? Is it 1D or 2D? At the moment you have an array of vectors, which is a bit odd. And also not legal C++, since variable length arrays are not legal C++.

Comment: You should really strongly consider redoing it with:
`vector< vector< Arc > > _adjacences`. Much saner.

Comment: ```list``` is the adjacency list from _adjacences which is a vector of pointers, I tried to make the ```list``` a vector that has the integers

Comment: Got to agree, the mix of vector, pointer and arrays is really confusing. And now that I can see something of the Arc class I see no need for any pointers at all.

Comment: @Jeffrey I tried to, but I found it harder that way

Comment: @KingAzaiez OK, so the declaration of `list` is reasonable but unfortunately not actually legal C++, does that concern you?

Comment: should I redo it all using the main adjacencies vector that's it ?

Comment: @KingAzaiez You should show what you tried, because what you have now is also hard.

Comment: @KingAzaiez If I understand your issue, then the problem is that you split 'tops' and 'distance' into `list` and `listD` but then you want to put them back together again in `matrix`. Is that correct?

Comment: @john exactly, when I want to put them back together, I end up with the last distance of a row as the same distance in the row of the matrix

Comment: `std::vector <int> list[_adjacences.size()];` is not C++. You are using a compiler extension to declare a VLA of `std::vector <int>`. I think you mean `std::vector <int> list(_adjacences.size());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think `list` and `listD` are a mistake because you are separating information that should stay together. Instead you should construct `matrix` directly from `_adjacences`. Like this

```
vector< vector< Arc * > * > _adjacences = ...;

std::vector<vector<int>> matrix(_adjacences.size(), vector<int>(_adjacences.size()));
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++) {
    for (auto j : *_adjacences[i]) {
         matrix[i][j->sommetArrive] = j->longueur;
    }
}
```

If you want `list` and `listD` as well as `matrix` then you can populate those in the same way that you are now.

Comment: thanks alot bro, I always make the mistake of splitting stuff and then putting them back together, as i find it easier to think and easier to make. It works